# Bing Image Search API filter by image size

Tags: image, search, bing

I'm working with Bing Image Search API using jsonp with jquery $.ajax.  I'm able to retrieve the search results. But I'm unable to find a way to filter results by image size. I can't find anything about this in the documentation. Does anyone know if there is a way to filter results by image size or do any type of filtration for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Image.Filters=Size:Small to filter by small images, you can also use medium and large.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete sample (The selected answer led to this) that might be helpful to someone who runs into this problem in the future:

```
request.Image = new ImageRequest();
request.Image.Filters = new string [1] {"Size:Small"};
```

More options to add to the "Filters" array can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560913.aspx).
HTH.